# How event handler inside JavaScript class/function got called?

Tags: javascript, function, class, oop, eventhandler

I'm quite new on JS and got stuck on this problem. So I have this constructor which I understand how its works EXCEPT for one thing. How does an event handler got called from inside of an object or function?

I thought event handler could only be placed on global scope directly, not inside a function/object or another block scopes.

```
class Counter {
    constructor(element, defaultValue) {
       this.element = element;
       this.value = defaultValue;

       this.valueDOM = element.querySelector('.value');
       this.valueDOM.textContent = this.value;

       this.increase = this.increase.bind(this);
       this.btnIncrease = element.querySelector('.increase');
       this.btnIncrease.addEventListener('click', this.increase);
    }
    increase() {
       this.value++;
       this.valueDOM.textContent = this.value;
    }
}

const counterOne = new Counter(document.querySelector('.counter-one'), 0);
const counterTwo = new Counter(document.querySelector('.counter-two'), 0);
```

The HTML is quite simple, just a plain old counter like this.

```
<div class="container counter-one">
    <span class="value">0</span>
    <button class="increase">+</button>
</div>
<div class="container counter-two">
    <span class="value">0</span>
    <button class="increase">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the placement of the `btnIncrease.addEventListener()` call or the placement of the `increase` definition? But no, both can be placed anywhere; passing closures as event listeners isn't even uncommon.

Comment: Do you understand what `this.increase = this.increase.bind(this)` is doing?

Comment: The placement of btnIncrease.addEventListener(). My understanding is an event handler could only be placed on global scope, otherwise the machine/browser/execution couldn't read it.

Comment: to bind the "this" value to the newly created object. otherwise it would be pointed out to window object and i got undefined/error result.

Comment: No, stuff needs to be in the global scope only for inline event listeners, like `<button onclick="handler(event)">`. An `addEventListener` call just needs to be executed, regardless from where, with the element (as receiver) and a function as argument.

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener` in this case is pointing directly at the local object's `this.increase` method. It is not pointing at the object's prototype function, but an actual distinct copy of that function which is attached to the object instance. Does that help?

Comment: I'm still quite confused, sorry. Why the browser could still read the `addEventListener` when it's placed inside an object/function? I thought `addEventListener` should be defined on global scope so it got stored on global memory and only then the browser can execute `addEventListener`

Comment: the second parameter of addEventListener is like a "pointer", pointing directly to the memory holding the function and its related context (the closure). when the event is triggered, the browser doesn't need to access a hidden function, because the parameter is connected to exactly the right copy of the function.

Comment: maybe imagine it like a string that is tied to a bell which is on the far side of a closed door. the string goes through a keyhole. you can pull the string and the bell will ring. but if you don't have the string you can't ring the bell.